# How to launch Reactjs.Net to IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, reactjs.net

I'm using ASP.net MVC 5 with ReactJS.net. It's working fine in Dev mode but I can't get react to work when I launch it to IIS. What has to be changed from DEV to Release to make it compile correctly? Should something be added to `bundle.config` or `web.config`?

Here is what my `bundle.config` looks like

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

    // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
    // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/jasny-bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js",
              "~/Scripts/bootbox.js",
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap-multiselect.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/inputanimations").Include(
              "~/Scripts/app/elements/textInputAnimations.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/jasny-bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/font-awesome.css",
              "~/Content/site.css",
              "~/Content/textbox.css",
              "~/Content/Scheduler.css",
              "~/Content/bootstrap-multiselect.css",
              "~/Content/dhtmlxgantt.css",
              "~/Content/dhtmlx.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/jqueryuicss").Include(
              "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
              "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dxhtmlgantt").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/dhtmlxgantt.js",
                    "~/Scripts/ext/dhtmlxgantt_smart_rendering.js",
                    "~/Scripts/app/ganttChartPropertyInitializer.js"
                ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/reactdependencies").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/react.js",
                    "~/Scripts/react-dom.js",
                    "~/Scripts/remarkable.js"
                ));

    bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/reactganttcomponents").Include(
                "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/ganttFilter.jsx",
                "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/InfoPanel.jsx",
                "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/index.jsx"
                ));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dxhtmlganttservices").Include(
        "~/Scripts/app/taskManager.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/GanttChartService.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/ganttChartStateManagerService.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/GanttFilter.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/infoPanelService.js",
        "~/Scripts/app/ganttToolbarControlInitializaer.js"
    ));

    bundles.Add(new BabelBundle("~/bundles/reacttoolbarcomponents").Include(
    "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/timelineScale.jsx",
    "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/newProject.jsx",
    "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/newSubProject.jsx",
    "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/newActivity.jsx",
    "~/Scripts/app/components/gantt/updateActivity.jsx"
    ));


    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dxhtmlsuite").Include(
        "~/Scripts/dhtmlx.js"));

     BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of searching I found out that none of my JavaScript files were being packaged when I published the app.
Inside of my scripts folder was empty. I had to delete all of my `*.jsx` files and then recreate them.